# Login browser too small in firefox?

Tags: css

i've no idea whats wrong here? http://46.21.111.41/~vhass/index.php/login - i've been trying everything. It works fine in Google chrome

Does anyone have a idea?

Comment: Can you at least provide us the steps you took to get to the error/problem please?

Comment: Also you have to correct the markup cause you have an unmatched end tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `width` to the form with the class .noradius.
If you add `width: 100%` it then works properly.